# Conditional operations based on matching (but not identical) index values / column labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to be able to execute dataframe operations using conditional statements that work using shared column/index labels between two dataframes.

pandas.mask() seems to work well enough when the two dataframes are of the same shape:

```
# Array of random integers.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (3, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), 
                  index=['7-1-2020', '8-1-2020', '9-1-2020'])
# Corresponding boolean array of same shape.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], (3, 5)), 
                  columns=list('ABCDE'), 
                  index=['7-1-2020', '7-2-2020', '9-1-2020'])

df1
Out[82]: 
          A  B  C  D  E
7-1-2020  5  7  0  8  4
8-1-2020  6  5  8  2  3
9-1-2020  9  7  5  3  4

df2
Out[83]: 
              A      B      C      D      E
7-1-2020  False  False  False  False  False
8-1-2020  False  False  False  False  False
9-1-2020   True   True   True   True  False

df1.mask(df2, 'FLAG')
Out[84]: 
             A     B     C     D  E
7-1-2020     5     7     0     8  4
8-1-2020     6     5     8     2  3
9-1-2020  FLAG  FLAG  FLAG  FLAG  4
```

I would have thought the same logic would apply to a differently sized dataframe with matching index values, but that does not appear to be the case:

```
# Array of random integers.
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(10, (6, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'), 
                  index=['7-1-2020', '8-1-2020', '9-1-2020', 
                         '7-1-2020', '8-1-2020', '9-1-2020'])
# Boolean array of different shape.
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([True, False], (3, 5)), 
                  columns=list('ABCDE'), 
                  index=['7-1-2020', '8-1-2020', '9-1-2020'])
df1.mask(df2, 'FLAG')


df1
Out[87]: 
          A  B  C  D  E
7-1-2020  9  7  7  5  1
8-1-2020  2  2  8  1  5
9-1-2020  8  4  0  2  5
7-1-2020  5  0  8  1  1
8-1-2020  0  3  8  8  4
9-1-2020  4  0  9  3  7

df2
Out[88]: 
              A      B     C      D      E
7-1-2020   True  False  True   True  False
8-1-2020  False  False  True  False  False
9-1-2020   True  False  True  False  False

df1.mask(df2, 'FLAG')
Out[86]: 
             A  B     C     D  E
7-1-2020  FLAG  7  FLAG  FLAG  1
8-1-2020  FLAG  2  FLAG  FLAG  5
9-1-2020     8  4  FLAG     2  5
7-1-2020     5  0  FLAG     1  1
8-1-2020  FLAG  3  FLAG     8  4
9-1-2020  FLAG  0  FLAG     3  7
```

I'm not exactly sure what is happening here, but it appears that the logic is applied in such a way that it is divided numerically based on the number of rows, and index value doesn't matter.

I'm not set on using pd.mask() if there is some other way I can perform a conditional operation on a dataframe based on another dataframe with matching (but not identical) column and index labels.  Thanks.